# How to rename buttons using wizard in formio?

Tags: angular, wizard, formio

I'm using formio with Angular 2 to render a custom form I've built. The thing is that when you create the form using wizard buttons `Next` and `Previous` are automatically added. Project should be localized for Germany and button names should also be in German.

Is there any way to rename/localize button titles? (the same problem is for the day component: the months are in English)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Formio translation (see https://github.com/formio/formio.js/wiki/Translations) or just disable the wizard buttons (https://github.com/formio/formio.js/wiki/Form-Renderer#options) and create your own which in return triggers the navigation events.

You could something like this:

```
var options = {
  language: 'en',
  i18n: {
    en: {
      cancel: 'Abort',
      previous: 'Back',
      next: 'Forward',
      submit: 'Execute'
    }
  }
};

Formio.createForm(document.getElementById('formio'), 'https://examples.form.io/wizard', options).then((instance) => {
  instance.language = options.language;
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/airarrazaval/e6pz2tcs/